# How do I flip a Three.js texture vertically?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to display some panoramic images in my "Street View"-like application with Three.js .

I used the [panorama example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_panorama_equirectangular) from the official webpage of Three.js as a base for the display of the images and it works OK. The problem is that my input images are **flipped vertically**. By vertical flip I mean the effect shown in [this image](http://www.online-image-editor.com/help/images/rotate_flip_02.png).

So my question is if I can, somehow, flip the textures loaded from the images or the sphere geometry I apply the textures to, in order to view the images as it should be.

Thank you.

Comment: You can flip/rotate the images inside the application by modifying the texture coordinates. But the easiest method would be to flip the images outside your application, namely in the image editor program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Luckily the vertical case is "natively" supported. Try with this:

```
texture.flipY = false;
```